# widget CSS conflicts with website CSS

Tags: css

I'm making a widget for my user so they can include in their website.

In file style.css which hosted in my user website:

```
p {
    font-size: 0;
}
```

In my widget - widget.css:

```
#mydiv {
  font-size:12px; 
}
```

However, when user include my CSS widget on their website. My CSS won't work and the one work is style.css. How to make my widget.css always work on top ?

---

I tried !important and it not work:

[image]

Comment: You should understand how CSS works. !Important is suited to cases where there is any other way..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use !important next to the declaration; like this:

```
#mydiv {
  font-size:12px !important; 
}
```

Some people will claim that using !important is always bad practice but that's not the case. In fact, when making a plug-in or widget that's going to run in other people's sites, then that's when it's actually good practice. Take a look here: http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

**Edit: after seeing your image in the question,** the problem is that it seems the ID `ulcfrmcontainer` refers to the container of the list and not the actual li elements within the containers. Try with this:

```
#ulcfrmcontainer li{
      font-size:12px !important; 
    }
```

Comment: That is not right. You don't know the details of the issue and !important should not be used just like that.

Comment: While `!important` *might* work, it is not going to be a good practice to use. Use more specificity in your widget selectors.

Comment: I disagree; it's there for a purpose and this is when to use it. Please explain why you THINK it "might" work and why you THINK it's bad practice.

Comment: @monocular: if you tried the !important rule and it doesn't work then the problem is elsewhere. May be there's some javascript that's modifying the style after the page loaded, or it could be some other issue.

Comment: @frenchie thank you so much for your effort. I'm not a beginner so i can understand what other people comment in your answer. I appreciate your effort to help me. Thank you so much.

Comment: @monocular Don't just go for the easy solution, go for the right solution. My answer includes both and when to use which.

Comment: @VinceCgto i appreciate your effort too, your answer is a full version. However, i can't vote up for 2 answer. In this case the answer from frenchie is more brief for me because i'm writing a widget and my user may usually have mistake when insert my widget before the other one. When they have mistake they will think my widget is nuisance...

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

**The right way:**

1) Make sure your path to the element is exactly right. For example

```
.wrapper div p {}
```

2) Make sure your css file is include **AFTER** the other one

**The other way (if the 1st doesn't work)**

Use !important. Like this:

```
font-size:12px!important;
```

**EDIT**

Looking at your latest screenshots it looks like you're adding the font-size to a div with id #ulcfrmcontainer instead of to unordened list.

Might wanna try:

```
#ulcfrmcontainer ul {
    font-size:12px;
}
```

Comment: So now you're going to be dealing with the order in which the user loads his stylesheets? The !important rule is good practice when making widgets or plug-ins that run in other people's websites.

Comment: While `!important` *might* work, it is not going to be a best practice. Try and use more specificity in your widget.

Comment: @BrettSantore: totally disagree. When making widgets, using !important IS good practice.

Comment: @frenchie Matching css paths & the stylesheet order are always better practice compared to !important. Imagine a website with dozens of widgets/plugins all using !important..

Comment: @VinceCgto: right, and when you're doing a plug-in or a widget, you don't know in advance the order in which the end-user of your code is going to load CSS files. That's why you NEED to use !important in this particular case.

Comment: @frenchie If you don't even understand specificity using `!important` is going to be a huge disaster. What your suggesting could lead a new programmer to the following. I have a widget and want to make sure that `color` on my `p`'s is *always* red. So, ill just add `div p { color:#f00 !important; }`. That is going to have horrible results in a production environment.

Comment: This is also a case of someone clearly new to the language, struggling to understand some of the basics of the technology, specificity. Showing how to code an advanced technique without explaining how and why it works, is just not the advice they should be getting.

Comment: @frenchie "you don't know in advance the order in which the end-user of your code is going to load CSS files" Yes, you do. Every proper developer knows you load the css (as you'd do with the JS) last. That is, if you're not gonna override the defined styles.

Comment: Just take 5 min to read this article: http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/ May be your mind will change.

Comment: Did you actually read the article? It's titled, WHEN using important is the right choice, not WHY. The article talks about specificity, which is my first option. The biggest problem of !important is, whenever something isn't working, people just toss it in the code instead of first looking at the bigger picture. You should, as I've mentioned time after time, FIRST check specificity and the stylesheet order, THEN ONLY IF that isn't working fall back to using !important. I'm not saying using !important is bad, I'm just saying you should use it as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

p is an existing html balise, and mydiv is an id, probably which select the parent div of your paragraph.

CSS apply rules following priority levels.

Here more informations:

[W3C wiki about selector priority](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Training/Priority_level_of_selector)

[Tips and tricks about it](http://hungred.com/useful-information/css-priority-order-tips-tricks/)

Try to solve your problem with those informations, and use "!important" only if there is no other solutions.
([Good article to determine if use !important is the right solution :)](http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/))

Hope it will help you to understand and resolve your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your widget in a div with an id that is unlikely to be used in the users site like 'widget-wrapper-div'. Or you could be more descriptive by including a one or two word description of the widget in the id such as 'partsearch-widget-wrapper'.

```
<div id="widget-wrapper-div">
    <div>
        Widget code...
    </div>
</div>
```

Then in your CSS you would start each style rule with `#widget-wrapper-div`

```
#widget-wrapper-div div{
    font-size: 12pt;
}
```